# Are there any guava overviews?

Tags: java, guava

Guava libraries are powerful, but I’m not sure what all the possibilities of this library are.

I’ve found interesting tutorials like http://scaramoche.blogspot.com/search/label/guava

But are there any overviews of everything the library can do?

Comment: +1 for link , found very useful .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Guava has added a new resource: Guava Explained:
https://github.com/google/guava/wiki

Answer (score 4):

The [API documentation](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html) is your best bet, along with the PDF slides linked at the guava [homepage.](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)

Answer (score 2):

It's worth to also check this one:
http://tomaszdziurko.pl/2012/02/google-guava/

Answer (score 1):

I uploaded simple unit tests using Guava to github. Most of them are from [Guava Explained](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/GuavaExplained). But some tests are solutions to problems in my workplace. Adding/modifying tests to the repo is always welcomed.

https://github.com/philipjkim/guava-example