# Getting started with guava

Tags: java, guava

How can I use Guava for my web application? I want to use it e.g. for testing instead of JUnit. Is that possible? What other uses can I have from Guava if I'm building webapps with JSP and servlets?

Comment: You mean Google Guava? There is a wiki has whole lot of info http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/w/list

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924479/are-there-any-guava-overviews?rq=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please read https://github.com/google/guava/wiki

**Guava is not a replacement of JUnit.**

Comment: Guava is sort of *extension for the JDK.* It can't replace a specialized library like JUnit or servlet-api, but it can help with a lot of things. Whatever you do, it's quite probable you find something useful there.

Comment: @maaartinus You should transform your comment in a response